# Xpath grabbing separate text in between link nodes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm currently retrieving text from inside `<a>` tags utilizing HtmlAgilityPack:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='acTrigger']/a"))
{
     lblTest1.Text = lblTest1.Text + ", " + node.InnerText.ToString();
}
```

and the web code looks like this

```
<li>
    <div class="acTrigger">
        <a href="/16014988/d/" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Battery')">
            Battery                                 <em>&nbsp;(1)</em>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="acTrigger">
        <a href="/15568540/d/" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Brakes')">
            Brakes                                 <em>&nbsp;(2)</em>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="acTrigger">
        <a href="/11436914/d/1979-honda-ct90-cables-lines" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Cables/Lines')">
            Cables/Lines                                 <em>&nbsp;(1)</em>
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Currently it is returning to me: `Battery  (1), Brakes  (2), Cables/Lines  (1)` which is obviously all of the inner text. What I would like to know is how to split the two bits apart so I can store them each in a list for later usage. Something along the lines of: `Battery, 1, Brakes, 2, Cables/Lines, 1` so as they are returned to me I can just toss them into lists.

The text in between the `<em>` tags are the number of results on the page that the `<a>` is taking you to. I could just parse the entire string after getting the line of text, but I feel as if there is a method to do this automatically with XPath and return one piece at a time for me to handle and store. I am very new to XPath and have been attempting to solve this for multiple days myself with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your XPath expression to `//div[@class='acTrigger']/a//text()[normalize-space()]` separate text nodes.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'm still trying to learn the XPath syntax, its a little odd.